# C function to remove all uppercase characters

Tags: c, string, char, uppercase

I need an efficient implementation of a function in C that would be given a char[] and it will remove all uppercase characters from it returning everything left.
e.g. if given `HELLOmy_MANname_HOWis_AREjohn_YOU__`

it should return `my_name_is_john__`

this is not a HW too easy to be one, but its 2am in my timezone and I think this would be a solution to a problem im facing in my code now!

any help is welcome!
cheers!=)

Comment: What you have tried so far and why hasn't it worked for you?

Comment: Memory-efficient or time-efficient?

Comment: If this is "too easy" to be homework, what's keeping you from writing it yourself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

maybe this?

```
i = j = 0;
while (s[i] != '\0') {
        if (!isupper(s[i]) 
                t[j++] = s[i];
        i++;
}
t[j] = '\0';
```

Comment: BTW, if you don't want have a separate variable `t` for the results, then simply replace it with `s` and remember to do this: `s[j] = '\0';`

Comment: You need to do `t[j] = '\0';` after the loop anyway (since you don't enter the loop body on NUL).

Answer (score 4):

How about <s>an algorithm</s> some pseudo-code?

```
initialize a rewrite pointer to the beginning of the string
for each character in the input string that isn't nul:
    if character is not an uppercase letter:
        add the character to rewrite pointer
        increment rewrite pointer
add nul terminator to rewrite pointer
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
#include <string.h> //strlen, strcpy
#include <ctype.h>  //isupper
#include <stdlib.h> //calloc, free

//removes uppercase characters
void rem_uc(char *str) {
    char *newStr = calloc(strlen(str), sizeof(char));
    char curChar;
    int i_str = 0, i_newStr = 0;
    do {
        curChar = str[i_str];
        if(!isupper(curChar)) {
            newStr[i_newStr] = curChar;
            i_newStr++;
        }
        i_str++;
    } while(curChar != 0);
    strcpy(str, newStr);
    free(newStr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Works in-place:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* removeUpperCase(char *s) {
    char *current = s;
    char *r = s; // r is the same rewrite pointer someone else mentioned in his answer =)
    do {
        if ((*current < 'A') || (*current > 'Z')) {
            *r++ = *current;
        }
    } while (*current++ != 0);
    return s;
}

int main() {
    char *s = strdup("HELLOmy_MANname_HOWis_AREjohn_YOU__"); // needed because constants cannot be modified
    printf(removeUpperCase(s));
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```